# Cache-control Immutable Header

Tags: caching, header, http-headers, cache-control

I was reading about immutable header and i came across with this article saying that:

> Cache-Control: max-age=365000000, immutable
>
> When a client supporting immutable sees this attribute it should
>   assume that the resource, if unexpired, is unchanged on the server and
>   therefore should not send a conditional revalidation for it (e.g.
>   If-None-Match or If-Modified-Since) to check for updates. Correcting
>   possible corruption (e.g. shift reload in Firefox) never uses
>   conditional revalidation and still makes sense to do with immutable
>   objects if you're concerned they are corrupted.

[source](https://bitsup.blogspot.com/2016/05/cache-control-immutable.html)

I cant understand this phrase "if unexpired, is unchanged on the server and therefore should not send a conditional revalidation"

Client, by default doesnt send a revalidation until the max-age is expired.

So whats the point define immutable in the first place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

People pressing the refresh button.

Facebook, who first proposed this immutable cache-control directive, have a [good post on this](https://engineering.fb.com/web/this-browser-tweak-saved-60-of-requests-to-facebook/) about how it saved them a huge amount of requests, including this quote:

> **The problem with reloads**
>
> The browser’s reload button exists to allow the user to get an updated
>   version of the current page. In order to meet this goal, when you
>   reload, browsers revalidate the page that you are currently on, even
>   if that page hasn’t expired yet. However, they also go a step further
>   and revalidate all sub-resources on the page — things like images and
>   JavaScript files.

Comment: When i reload my page, the requests hit the cache because it isnt expired yet. So no revalidation is happening, this is why i dont understand the immutable.

Comment: Depends on browser and exact refresh method. Try it on Firefox. On Facebook they are used from cache as they use this. Other sites get a 304 on refresh.